# Probability: $p(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty G_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty }p(G_n)$

Tags: probability

What is the name of the theorem that say that

$$p\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty }p(G_n),$$
if $G_n\subset G_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and 
$$p\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty }p(G_n),$$
if $G_{n+1}\subset G_n$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: It's a consequence of $\sigma$-additivity of the probability measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upward and downward continuity of a probability measure

Comment: Or "continuity from above" and "continuity from below." It's worth mentioning that the latter property requires that the measure of the first set be finite (which is always true for a probability measure).

Answer (score 1):

You can also note that when $\{ G_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing $P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} G_i) = P(\lim_{n \to \infty} \cup_{i=1}^{n} G_i) = P(\lim_{n \to \infty} G_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(G_n)$, which is just an application of the dominated convergence theorem.  The same argument works for $P(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} G_i)$ when $\{ G_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing.